# Android remove layouts inflateds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater

I do this to introduce layouts over another layout.

But I do not know how I could remove every one of them when needed.

```
myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.segundacapa, null);
this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.thirdshape, null);
this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

For example if I want to remove the layout segundacapa what should I do?

Comment: Clear your question. what do you mean by `removing layout segundacapa`? what do you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank for your answer. Maybe my new answer, clear my question....

Answer (score 0):

You will set tag all layout. When remove layout make for each parent's all child than cotrol its tag.